# Force "#" links to function normally with .htaccess and <base> tags

Tags: html, ajax, .htaccess, href

I'm using .htaccess to achieve "pretty" URLs on my website. As a result, I am forced to include a `<base>` tag in my headers. Now trying to use AJAX, and this causes any `href="#"` links to return to the index page.

(For example, clicking on `<a href="#">Link</a>` on `website.com/games/` returns you to `website.com/#` rather than doing nothing - as a # link should.)

How can I work around this? Any suggestions would be much appreciated - perhaps an alternative to stopping style sheets breaking with .htaccess rather than `<base>`.

Comment: Try using javascript:void(0); instead of # ?

Comment: That'll do! Didn't even think :)